# Symbolic evaluation of Product

Tags: performance-tuning, simplifying-expressions, symbolic

```
 F = 
   ((1. - Subscript[p, 4])^(-Subscript[p, 3]) - (1. - Subscript[p, 4]*
     Exp[-Subscript[p, 1]*Subscript[x, i]^Subscript[p,2]])^(-Subscript[p,3]))/
     ((1. - Subscript[p, 4])^(-Subscript[p, 3]) - 1.)

 f = FullSimplify[D[F, Subscript[x, i]]]

 L := Product[f, {i, 1, n}]  // AbsoluteTiming
```

In *Mathematica* 7.0, how can I get the `Product` expression shown above to evaluate in a reasonable time without specifying `n`?.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Do you expect it to have a nice form? It shouldn't, that I can see.

Comment: Notice that if I remove  p1*p2*p3*p4 from density function f then Product[] works fine even though it takes long time. The question is why product[] does not work in the previous density function f ?